# Database query a complex select statment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which have id name and manager id

```
id  name  manager_id
1  myName  4
2  alex    3
3  brain   2
4  someone 1
```

Now i have to write the query which display the result like that

```
myname someone
alex brain
brain alex
someone myname
```

Means we have to display name and mnager Name according to the Id

Comment: Read about left join. (i wouldn't call it complex ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

join the table with itself:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name FROM my_table AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2 ON( t1.manager_id = t2.id )
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this return what youre after?

```
SELECT
  t1.name AS Name,
  t2.name AS manager
FROM tab t1
  JOIN tab t2 ON(t1.manager_id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  employee.name,
  manager.name
FROM
  tablename employee
INNER JOIN
  tablename manager
ON
  employee.manager_id = manager.id
```

Replace `tablename` with the actual table name.